# Mock Static final method call returning null using PowerMock

Tags: java, junit, powermock

Im trying to write a test case for Student class, for getNumber method. And, it has to make a call to final static method of Enrollment class. In my junit I have used PowerMock to mock the static calls, but instead of returning instance of enrollment, its returning a null value.

```
public class Student{

 public static String getNumber(){
            Enrollment enroll =   Enrollment.getInstance("xyz");
         return "123";
  }
}

public class Enrollment {
  public static final Enrollment getInstance(String id){
    return new Enrollment;
  }
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Student.class, Enrollment.class})
public class StudentTest{

@Test
public void testGetNumber(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Enrollment.class);
        Enrollment enrollment = PowerMockito.mock(Enrollment.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Enrollment.getInstance(Mockito.anyString())) .thenReturn(enrollment);
            Student.getNumber(); 
        Mockito.verify(Enrollment.getInstance(Mockito.anyString())); 
   }
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: You should probably use `PowerMockito.verifyStatic()` instead of `Mockito.verify()`

Comment: verifyStatic method is to verify whether is call is made or not. Here the problem is Mockito is returning null instead of mocked value.

Comment: I can see no place where you check that the returned value is `null`

Comment: Try using doReturn instead of when().thenReturn()

Comment: Tried doReturn(), still getting null as response